# Jquery Mobile 1.3 slider conflicts with panel

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

I am trying to set up a JQuery Mobile 1.3 site that uses a panel and a slider.

Problem is, that using the slider triggers the panel, which opens on a "swiperight" event, as I am moving the slider to the right. The slider will be for pagination, the panel for a menu.

Code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kMARn/1/

Move the slider to the right and the panel will open.

I have tried using the .not() selector for the panel to not react on the slider:

```
$(document).not("#slider").on("swiperight", function(event, ui) {
    $("#myPanel").panel("open");
});
```

But it won't work, the panel opens when i move the slider to the right. Tried a bunch of variants too, but I'm lost...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The `not()` method removes a set of elements from a set of elements. In your case `$(document)` contains only a single element - the document. Nothing to remove here.

Comment: @Rainer Mohr, Have you seen my simple solution below?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following solution is more a workaround. It should be relatively reliable though.

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    var menu_available = true;

    $(document).on("swiperight", function(event, ui) {
        if (menu_available) $("#myPanel").panel("open");
    });

    $("#slider").on("slidestop", function( event, ui ) { 
        menu_available = false;
        window.setTimeout(function() {menu_available= true;},250);
    }); 
});
```

The variable `menu_available` is `false` for a 250 milliseconds right after the slide stops. The `window.setTimeout` block will reset the variable so that the menu is available again.

This is a stupid workaround, but jQuerys function `event.stopEventPropagation()`, which IMHO would be the correct way to go, didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but you can disable swipe-to-close by setting the data-swipe-close attribute to "false" on the panel div.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/options.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used this simple code, without *data-swipe-close = "false"* in panel.
Keeping panel close with swipe right, outside of the slider.

```
$('#panel').find('#slider')
    .on('slidestop',function(e,ui) {
        var value = e.target.value;
        //...operations with slider value...
    })
    .parent().on('swiperight',function(e,ui) {
        e.stopPropagation();  //block panel close
    })
```

Comment: You are a star Stefano. Exactly what i have been looking for for months. Thanks

Comment: tnk! I was also a lot of time working to solve this problem, then the solution has come out randomly

Comment: may be @Rainer Mohr can use this?

Answer (score 0):

From the 1.3.0b1 Docs for Swipe:

> "Triggers when a horizontal drag of 30px or more (and less than 75px
>   vertically) occurs within 1 second duration"

This applies to and can be configured for `swiperight` too. You can make the slider small in length and this would ensure that both the slider event stop and the swipe are not triggered at the same time, yet that may not be practical for all scenarios.

What might be better is to bind the swipe right to a `DIV` or section of the page. By this, I mean if you have a 75 px div box on the left hand side of the display, and when a swipe event occurred within that div, it could trigger the menu.

I feel the logic here might be better controlled by a button, much like used in the Facebook App to display there slide out menu. In the Dolphin browser on Android, this type of event also triggers a bookmark menu, so if a page has a swiperight event and trigger it, I sometimes get both the event and the bookmark menu from the App. Annoying!

I did fork your jsfiddle and will play with it more (http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Hg2pw/). FYI, they have JQM 1.3.0b1 in their available frameworks so you don't have to link it in your HTML. If I find some more info, I will comment here.